# if statement within PHP Function

Tags: php, function

```
function sendSMS($msg, 
                 $to, 
                 $profileID="(if (@$_GET['debug'] == "true") { 
                                 echo "21409"; 
                              } else { 
                                 echo "21410"; })", 
                 $user="User", 
                 $pass="Pass", 
                 $serverID="", 
                 $msgid="", 
                 $shortCode="00000"){
```

I would like it so that when Debug is called it gives a different number

Debug True = 21409

Debug False = 21410

Comment: I think you might be using the function weirdly, generally, you pass values to a function, you don't just set the default params and not ever change them... If they are hard coded, they shouldn't be params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to write an if statement in the signature of the function??

And echo directly writes the string into the output stream.
What you need to do is to establish the variable $profileId depending on $_GET[DEBUG] and use it in the statement that sends the email.

```
function sendSMS($msg, 
                 $to,  
                 $user="User", 
                 $pass="Pass", 
                 $serverID="", 
                 $msgid="", 
                 $shortCode="00000"){


    if ($_GET['debug'] == "true") { 
        $profileID = "21409"; 
    } else { 
        $profileID= "21410";
    }

    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

well...You can't do it, logic goes in the body of the function, not in the header.
And since the value for `$profileID` is calculate anyway, why would u even put it in the header of the function?

```
function sendSMS($msg, 
                 $to, 

                 $user="User", 
                 $pass="Pass", 
                 $serverID="", 
                 $msgid="", 
                 $shortCode="00000"){
$profileID=($_GET['debug'])?21409:21410;
...
...
}
```